# How can I play a mp4 movie using Moviepy and Pygame

Tags: python, video, pygame, mp4, moviepy

How do you play an mp4 video in Pygame?

I have tried pygame.movie but this does not work...

Theres also moviepy, but I am having trouble changing the title of the window that pops up. It says "MoviePy", not sure how to change that.

```
import moviepy
from moviepy.editor import *
import os


os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED"] = "1"

clip = VideoFileClip('qq.mp4')


clip.preview()

execfile("qq.py") # Execute my game right after the clip shows
```

How would I change the title from "MoviePy" to my "my game name"

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First: you can use

```
import moviepy

print(moviepy.__file__)
```

to find source code and see how it works.

---

After searching in source code you will see that it uses `pygame` to display it and you can try to use pygame function `set_caption()` to change title.

```
from moviepy.editor import *
import pygame

pygame.display.set_caption('Hello World!')

clip = VideoFileClip('video.mp4')
clip.preview()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: This example doesn't work for me:
IndexError: bytes to write exceed buffer size

Comment: @Junix better create question - you will have more place to put FULL error message and code. It seems it has nothing to do with main problem in this question - which was adding caption to window.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried converting from mp4 to the .mpg file format (MPEG-1 video, MPEG-1 Audio Layer III (MP3) sound) using `ffmpeg` video conversion program (http://ffmpeg.org/):

```
ffmpeg -i <infile> -vcodec mpeg1video -acodec libmp3lame -intra <outfile.mpg>
```

(Pygame can playback video and audio from basic encoded MPEG-1 video files)

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I did what you said but I get this error message when using Pygame movie:

raise NotImplementedError(MissingPygameModule)
NotImplementedError: movie module not available
(ImportError: No module named movie)

Comment: @user2648117 Are you using pygame or not? In your example you don't. If you are: pygame.movie don't work. It's outdated.

Comment: I don't mind how I show the opening video. It can be pygame or anything else. Because I could not find anything in pygame, I decided to use moviepy just to show it and then after it finishes, I use `execfile("qq.py")` to go straight to my game. My problem with moviepy is that I don't know how to change the title bar.  It shows "MoviePy"...

Answer (score 2):

```
from moviepy.editor import *

import pygame

pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_caption('Show Video on screen')

video = VideoFileClip('name_of_your video.mp4')
video.preview()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code and it work,you need moviepy and pydub libraries to let it work.

```
id_path='我不是购物狂 EP15 Rebirth Of Shopping Addicts EP15_HIGH.mp4' # Name of the video
au_path='Produce.wav'
import moviepy.editor as mp
video = mp.VideoFileClip(vid_path)
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play
video.preview()
song = AudioSegment.from_wav(au_path)
play(song)
```