# Can you use a animation with pygame without having all the frames as a picture?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I want to display an animation using pygame, python  without having multiple jpg's or png's using for ex a mp4 or a animation file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pygame had a library called `movie` but it isn't supported anymore so you can't import it.

But there's still a python package that can do this, just take a quick look at this:
[How can I play a mp4 movie using Moviepy and Pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41760385/how-can-i-play-a-mp4-movie-using-moviepy-and-pygame)

You can download MoviePy via pip, see https://pypi.org/project/moviepy/ for mor information!