# PyGame video get out of sync

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, pygame, moviepy

So, I want to make a video player that plays the video and the audio in sync. I also don't want to use ffmpeg because I would like to make my script not need a dependency of ffmpeg and force my friends to install ffmpeg to their computer and set the path and stuff. So right now my code is:

```
from moviepy.editor import *
import pygame

pygame.display.set_caption('Hello World!')

clip = VideoFileClip('yeetus.mp4')
clip.preview(fps=30)

pygame.quit()
```

(From [How can I play a mp4 movie using Moviepy and Pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41760385/how-can-i-play-a-mp4-movie-using-moviepy-and-pygame#41771413))

When I try to move the window somewhere else it freezes right and the audio kinda just iterates in a specific timestamp. But when you stop dragging it, the audio plays where it was, but the video is out of sync. Is there a fix to this issue? If not, is there an alternative? Thanks

edit: still open to answers btw

Comment: I’d recommend looking at the source code for moviepy’s preview. It is quite crude - you may be able to improve it, or decide that a completely different approach is better.

Comment: @TomBurrows That does look crude but I am looking through it right now.